# How do I select a string after a radio button, with Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Code sample:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" name="SomeName" value="3" checked>
    My String $10.00
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How do I select 'My String $10.00' to hide it from the client?

```
$('???').next().hide();
```

Edit:

The HTML above is auto generated..I have no control over it....

Comment: You should be using a <label> tag, as that would make the radio button selectable by clicking the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no control of the HTML I would go with one of the following solutions.

**First solution:** I don't think you can use hide() on text nodes in jQuery since that function only operates on elements (I'm speculating). But here's how you can remove the text.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[type='radio'][name='SomeName']").parent().contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType != 1; }).remove();
    });
```

You can read more about contents() [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/contents).

**Second solution:** You can inject span elements around the text nodes and hide the spans.

```
var parent = $("input[type='radio'][name='SomeName']").parent();
parent.contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType != 1; }).wrap("<span></span>");
parent.find("span").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[name=SomeName]').parent().text();
```

If you want to hide that text, you would be best off enclosing it in a paragraph, span or label tag, so you could do something like this:

```
$('input[name=SomeName]').parent().find('span').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery does not allow easy access to text nodes. Perhaps you could change the HTML to something like the following?

```
...
<input type="radio" id="myID"/>
<label for="myID">My String $10.00</label>
...
```

Then you can do:

```
$("input[type=radio]").next().hide();
```

or, if you want to have it work no matter the order of the elements or any other stuff in between:

```
$("input[type=radio]").closest("td").find("label").hide();
```

---

Since you edited the post to mention you have no control over the HTML, try something along these lines:

```
// Tiny jQuery extension to provide $().outerHTML();
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return $($('<div></div>').html(this.clone())).html(); 
} 
var radioButton = $("input[type=radio]");
var parentElement = radioButton.parent();
var radioHTML = radioButton.outerHTML();
var hiddenText = radioButton.parent().text();

// Hide the text:
parentElement.html(radioHTML);

// Display the text again:
parentElement.html(radioHTML + hiddenText);
```

Answer (score 0):

he says he can't control the HTML.

But it's true, you can't access the text node easily to use hide() on it.

Hack sol'n: try reading everything in the  into a var, stripping out everything after the tag with a regexp and then re-loading the result.

```
var chunk = $('input[name="SomeName"]').parent().html();
$('input[name="SomeName"]').parent().empty().append( chunk.replace(/(<[^>]+>).*/, '$1') );
```

or something like that (not tested)